# Superview not resizing with subviews

Tags: cocoa, autolayout

I have a window into which I horizontally add two subviews. Into each subview, I place a variable number of subviews made up of a vertical slider, a text field rotated 90 degrees and placed to the left of the slider and another textfield, placed just under the slider. The slider subview's constraints are done in code, the parent views are both done in IB. When I add more slider views to the left window than the subview can handle in its default size, it resizes horizontally and forces the window's content view (and window) to also resize horizontally. Great, that's just what I want. But if I add more slider subviews than can fit in the right subview, they just get squeezed together and the subview does not expand as the left. I layout the slider views using code with this category converted to support NSViews, instead of UIVews:

[UIView+AutoLayout](http://www.spikesoft.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/SliderTest.zip)[1](http://www.spikesoft.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/SliderTest.zip): https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout

The constraints for the left and right subviews are more or less the same. I can't figure out why the right view does not resize as the left view does.

Here is a link to a sample project that demonstrates the problem:
[SliderTest](http://www.spikesoft.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/SliderTest.zip)

Some someone help me out with this?
Also, a secondary question as I think my slider view could use a little work:
When a view is rotated using setFrame(Center)Rotation, do the top, right, bottom and top edges remain along the same edges or do they reflect the new orientation of the rotated view?
Thanks

Comment: After removing the constraint between the two subviews, I see that the right subview expands toward the center. I guess this is the expected behavior, but I need the right subview to expand to the right and force the window to expand accordingly. I'll keep playing around and googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The constraint between the left view and right edge of the window was fixed at 233 instead of >= 233. I had this at some point in the past, as I was adjusting the constraints to achieve the desired behavior and just overlooked this one through the troubleshooting process.